# transition does not work in the FF with parent overflow:hidden

Tags: css, firefox, overflow, transition

This is example of the modal that i have the problem with

http://codepen.io/meded90/pen/DBFwo

sass:

```
body
  .wrap
    visibility: hidden
  &.in
    //TODO: why if i delete this like, animation in the firefox going to work?
    overflow: hidden
    .wrap
      visibility: visible
.wrap
  position: fixed
  z-index: 1 
  left: 0
  top: 0
  right: 0
  bottom: 0
  background-color: rgba(#000,.4)

.modal
  +transition(all 0.3s ease-out)
  background-color: #000
  color: red
  display: inline-block
  +translate(0, -200%)
  left: 50%
  top: 50%
  position: absolute 
  opacity: 0
  &.in
    opacity: 1 
    +translate(0, 0)
```

html

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="modal">
  hi...
</div>
</div>
<button>Open</button>
```

js

```
$('button').click(function(){
  console.log($('.modal'))
  $('.modal').addClass('in')
  $('body').addClass('in')

})

$('.wrap').click(function(){
  $('.modal').removeClass('in')
  $('body').removeClass('in')
})
```

if i delete the line number 7 "overflow: hidden" than animation in the FF work as expected but with that line it does not work. Anybody can advice me something how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs due to the flattening of descendant elements as per the spec: [transform-style property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120911/#transform-style).

Chrome seems not to have this behavior, which explains your Firefox problem. As for a workaround, the best option is to put the modal div after the wrap div and float it on top using relative positioning. For the lightbox effect, make a lightbox div which is also un-nested (a child of body), and use z-index to position behind the modal, but in front of all other page elements. Now you can simply toggle both the lightbox and modal divs between `element.style.display = "block"` and `element.style.display = "none"`.

Comment: It does not work, since I'm sharing widget for third-party sites, and they have to scroll worth imeno on body

'
body.in
  overflow: hidden
  > *
    overflow: hidden
.wrap
  overflow: visible
'

Comment: I see, your use case definitely would prevent that. The issue is due to the flattening. What happens in this cases is that the final position appears for the visibility toggle rather than the whole animation. This is actually the specified behavior. Due to the 3rd party nature, even a hack solution is hard to come by. If you want to try to force it, I think the best bet (if it is possible at all) would be the positioning properties left, right, top, and bottom. Without a full example, it is hard to help more.